# Should I use the JSON:API include module or let the front application handle the related entities display?

Tags: 8

to get a related entities using the json:api I can use ex: **?include=uid,uid.user_picture** in the parameter, and all the related entities will be returned in the **included** object, then the front application needs to apply some logic to get the entity(ex: node)+ related entity fields (ex: author email) and then I want to get the author is image , so the front will need to handle a lot of loops, so I have used the **[JSON:API Include](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships)** module it works by embeding the relationships one inside another automaticall,but it have some drawbacks so can any one help me to figure out what is the best solution ?

1. without **[JSON:API Include](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_include)** module :

   > the json HTTP response size will be smaller,also the json structure respect the [JSON API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) which  make it more stable and understandable(relationships , included..) 
   >   **but** the processing in the front application will be heavier if we have
   >   a lot of relationships.[image]
2. with **[JSON:API Include](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_include)** module :

   > easy processing for the front application **but** the json HTTP response size will be bigger ,and the [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) will be broken(no **relationships** or  **included** object all will be shifted into the data object).[image]

Comment: use it if you need simplified results to be used in the front end

Comment: i'm the author of  **JSON:API Include**, when you use module the front end developer will happy and save a lot of time ;)